# Regex lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am using a regex to find:

```
test:?
```

Followed by any character *until* it hits the next:

```
test:?
```

Now when I run this regex I made:

```
((?:test:\?)(.*)(?!test:\?))
```

On this text:

```
test:?foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2test:?foo=bar&baz=footest:?foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2
```

I expected to get:

```
test:?foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2

test:?foo=bar&baz=foo

test:?foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2
```

But instead it matches everything. Does anyone with more regex experience know where I have gone wrong? I've used regexes for pattern matching before but this is my first experience of lookarounds/aheads.

Thanks in advance for any help/tips/pointers :-)

Comment: Are you just wanting to split on `test:?`? If you are, your environment will provide a way of doing that without regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you could explore a greedy version.
(expanded)

`(test:\? (?: (?!test:\?)[\s\S])* )`

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly and I've learned more of the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The Perl program below

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$_ = "test:?foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2test:?foo=bar&baz=footest:?foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2";

while (/(test:\?  .*?) (?= test:\? | $)/gx) {
  print "[$1]\n";
}
```

produces the desired output from your question, plus brackets for emphasis.

```
[test:?foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2]
[test:?foo=bar&baz=foo]
[test:?foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2]
```

Remember that [regex quantifiers are greedy](/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions/2759417#2759417) and want to gobble up as much as they can without breaking the match. Each subsegment to terminate as soon as possible, which means `.*?` semantics.

Each subsegment terminates with either another `test:?` or end-of-string, which we look for with `(?=...)` zero-width lookahead wrapped around `|` for alternatives.

The pattern in the code above uses [Perl’s `/x` regex switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#/x) for readability. Depending on the language and libraries you’re using, you may need to remove the extra whitespace.

Comment: I used your sytnax in a regex tester but the match still gave me a string containing two "test:?" strings. I am using Java so I assume it might by syntax related? (I removed the whitespaces for testing). Thanks for your help though I learned a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Three issues:

- `(?!)` is a negative lookahead assertion. You want `(?=)` instead, requiring that what comes next is `test:?`.
- The `.*` is greedy; you want it non-greedy so that you grab just the first chunk.
- You're wanting the last chunk also, so you want to match `$` as well at the end.

End result:

```
(?:test:\?)(.*?)(?=test:\?|$)
```

I've also removed the outer group, seeing no point in it. All RE engines that I know of let you access group 0 as the full match, or some other such way (though perhaps not when finding all matches). You can put it back if you need to.

(This works in PCRE; not sure if it would work with POSIX regular expressions, as I'm not in the habit of working with them.)

If you're just wanting to split on `test:?`, though, regular expressions are the wrong tool. Split the strings using your language's inbuilt support for such things.

Python:

```
>>> re.findall('(?:test:\?)(.*?)(?=test:\?|$)',
... 'test:?foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2test:?foo=bar&baz=footest:?foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2')
['foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2', 'foo=bar&baz=foo', 'foo2=bar2&baz2=foo2']
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want `((?:test:\?)(.*?)(?=test:\?))`, although you haven't told us what language you're using to drive the regexes.

The `.*?` matches *as few* characters as possible without preventing the whole string from matching, where `.*` matches *as many* as possible (is greedy).

Depending, again, on what language you're using to do this, you'll probably need to match, then chop the string, then match again, or call some language-specific match_all type function.

By the way, you don't need to anchor a regex using a lookahead (you can just match the pattern to search for, instead), so this will (most likely) do in your case:

```
test:[?](.*?)test:[?]
```

Comment: If you're going to take that approach, then you need to change the `?!` to `?=`.

Comment: -1, lookahead is needed. Without it every other required match would not match because `test:` already been consumed.