# Regular expression to match (, but not \(

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to match every ( and ) in a string, but exclude \( and \).  This is so that I can replace every parentheses but keep the ones with the slash in front of them.

Example String: (,)(5)(5)( )(\()(9)(1)(87x)(100 )(ASP\)( )(5)

Edit:
Desired Result after replace: ,55 \(9187x100 ASP\) 5
Then i can remove the \ and get my desired string ,55 (9187x100 ASP) 5

Edit: I am using VB.NET

Comment: What language are you using? Some languages will allow you to use a [lookbehind](http://stackoverflow.com/a/546265/1721527) or [lookahead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9440084/1721527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a look-behind you can match only "(" or ")" that are not immediately proceeded by a "\":

```
/(?<!\\)[\(\)]/
```

Comment: Does using a look-behind offer an advantage over a negated character class ?

Comment: A look-behind doesn't consume a character, so you don't have the issue of matching more than you want to replace.

Answer (score 2):

This will match parenthesis without slashes in front of them (and the character before them):

```
[^\\]\(
```

Comment: This would fail to match an open parenthesis at the beginning of a string, as he has in his example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to take context into account. So first you want to not have a `\` and then you want a `(` or a `)`.

```
[^\\]\(
[^\\]\)
```

But you can put both paranthesis in a character class

```
[^\\][\)\(]
```